# How do I escape spaces on the Windows command line?

Tags: windows, android-emulator, cmd

I'm trying to launch Android emulator with SD card support from Windows cmd.

I have tried:

```
emulator -sdcard C:/Documents and Settings/User/sdcard.img -avd avd_tablet
```

It is not working: *invalid command-line parameter: and*

```
emulator -sdcard C:/Documents^ and^ Settings/User/sdcard.img -avd avd_tablet
```

It is not working with "^": *invalid command-line parameter: and^*

```
emulator -sdcard "C:/Documents and Settings/User/sdcard.img" -avd avd_tablet
```

It is not working with quotes: *invalid command-line parameter: and*

```
emulator -sdcard C:/Documents\ and\ Settings/User/sdcard.img -avd avd_tablet
```

It is not working with backslash escaping: *invalid command-line parameter: and*

```
emulator -sdcard C:/"Documents and Settings"/User/sdcard.img -avd avd_tablet
```

It is not working with partial backslash escaping: *invalid command-line parameter: and*

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Google](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html) describes, you have to specify the **relative path to the SD card image**.

If your SDK is installed at *C:\Documents and Settings\User\Android SDK*, start the emulator this way:

```
emulator -sdcard "..\..\..\sdcard.img" -avd avd_tablet
```

Answer (score 2):

```
emulator -sdcard "C:\Documents and Settings\User\sdcard.img" -avd avd_tablet
```

should work. If it doesn't, then the program you are using is broken and you might have to look up how to pass paths with spaces to it. The Windows command line (unlike Unix shells) does no parameter parsing of commands; the program just gets a string with the complete command line and has to figure things out by itself.

Comment: If the program is broken, things like `C:\DOCUME~1\…` might work.

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo but @Salvatore is using slash `/` in stead of backslash ``\``.

Comment: Should not matter. The Windows APIs transparently convert slashes into backslashes for paths. The only place where it *does* matter is built-in commands of `cmd` which use `/` for options and sometimes are confused when given slashed paths.

Comment: @Joey: I think you're right. Android emulator "-sdcard" parameter doesn't accept spaces. I think I have to use relative path or "DOCUME~1" notation. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Technically Mikael is right here because the documentation explicitly states *“Optionally, you can specify a path relative to the current working directory.”*, so an absolute path is not supported at all.

Comment: Actually the absolute path is working for "path without spaces". And moreover the relative path is not working for "path with spaces": "..\..\a folder\sdcard.img". So I think is a Google fault.